# Windows Command to Delay The Output And Then Find a String

Tags: regex, windows, command-line, timeout, findstr

I am trying to do the following on Windows Command Line:

`gpresult /Scope User /v` Gets the results of the current user group policies set, then using a command such as ping or timeout, create a delay and then execute

```
findstr "ScreenSaveActive"
```

I have tried to do the following, for example, trying to accomplish the above but have been unsuccessful:

```
gpresult /Scope User /v | timeout /t 5 /nobreak | findstr "ScreenSaveActive"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier done in Powershell with a command such as:

```
gpresult /Scope User /v | out-string -stream | select-string "ScreenSaveActive"
```

And you could run it from cmd like:

```
Powershell -Command "gpresult /Scope User /v | out-string -stream | select-string 'ScreenSaveActive'"
```